# Typescript property type same as property which has multiple types

Tags: typescript, types

In my data store, I have two properties

data, backupData

I am trying to define that backupData must be of the same type as data.

However,

```
class ClassC{
   data: InterfaceA | InterfaceB
   backupData: InterfaceA | InterfaceB 
}
```

does not ensure that backup is the SAME type as data.

Should backupData be of type any or is there a way to write this?

---

As a follow up for others who come across this, the solution worked using the answer below by doing:

```
class ClassC<T>{
   data: T;
   backupData: T;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  Right now it's not clear what `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` are (although I can guess) and you are not initializing your class properties (so that there would be errors with `--strict` compiler options).  Basically you either want the class to be generic, or you need to refactor (e.g., push the properties down into a new union-typed property; give up on a `class` entirely and just use a union type) but the right way to proceed kind of depends on a little more use case details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to solve this with a generic type.

```
interface A {
  foo: string;
}

interface B {
  bar: string;
}

class MyClass<T extends A | B> {
  data: T;
  backupData: T;
}

const example1: MyClass<A> = {
  data: { foo: 'foo' },
  backupData: { foo: 'foo' }
}

const example2: MyClass<B> = {
  data: { foo: 'foo' }, // compiler error
  backupData: { bar: 'bar' }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What I ended up doing is breaking down interface A and B and creating a more basic interface that A and B extend. Then I used that in data | backupData. I will study your example more and try to implement this.